# PHP Update HTML elements on every read

Tags: javascript, php

As I am a novice in PHP scripting, I wrote a PHP script that has HTML tags which creates a UI and later want to update its UI values via a PHP code block.

Something like below:

index.php

```
<div>
<div id="ecg">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p><b>Electrocardiac Diagram &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</b></p>
    <p><b>(ECG) &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</b></p>
</div>
<div>
    <img id="ecgimg" src="images/ecg.jpg" alt="ECG" height="200" width="300" align="middle">
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
</div>
```

Later as stated above in same file:

```
<?php
while (1){
$read = $file->read();
$s=0;
$y=0;
$ecg="";
$sp="";
$bp="":
$oxy="";
$temp = "";

............

$ecg=$read;

.....
?>
```

How can I update the HTML text div id="ecg" with the one I have read from file - say I want to make the text as

```
(ECG Normal)
```

Comment: When you say "later in a PHP block" do you mean once the page has loaded fully or are you trying to populate an HTML template with variables from your PHP code?

Comment: I actually have the PHP code after creating the UI elements and  loop infinitely reading the file

Comment: No way, Once you have echoed the html content, it will be sent to browser. You cannot update it even you have a loop. You need to change html via ajax like something

Comment: Look into using AJAX. That will let you display data dynamically using PHP. I will say this though be careful how you read the file. If you read the file constantly per page load you could end up DOS-ing yourself.

Comment: Thanks then how will I open the file for reading in one attempt and read its content continuously?

Comment: Look into AJAX, try stuff out and then come back when you've tried something out.

Answer (score 0):

Once the page is shown to the user you can't use plain PHP to update the page as the page is no longer on the server but on the client's computer.

You need to use Javascript and AJAX to read the file and update the page.

You could read this to help you:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Update:

Here is what your html file should look like:

```
<div>
    <div id="ecg">
        <?php
            $read = $file->read();
            echo $read;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img id="ecgimg" src="images/ecg.jpg" alt="ECG" height="200" width="300" align="middle">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
    setInterval(readFile, 3000);

    function readFile() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "readFile.php"
        })
       .done(function( data ) {
           $('#ecg').html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

In the readFile.php all you need is:

```
<?php
    $read = $file->read();
    echo $read;
?>
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thanks then how will I open the file for reading in one attempt and read its content continuously?